# Sharing icons missing from all online sites - MAC after Google sync

Tags: macos, google-chrome, sync, icons, macbook-pro

I accidentally synced my Mac with Google, lost all bookmarks, etc., but the most puzzling thing is that there are now NO "share" icons on ANY online sites I visit. None.

I used to see FB, Twitter, email sharing icons on almost every story and video. Now, there are NONE.

Comment: What solution are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing any browser extensions.

In addition to browsing history, bookmarks, etc., Google Chrome can also sync browser extensions.  Browser extensions (such as [AdBlock](https://getadblock.com/)) can remove ("block") social media buttons, as many users prefer not to see them.